# Nonzero Curvature implies local noncollinearity of any three points.

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, curves, curvature, osculating-circle

Let $\gamma:(a,b)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ be a regular smooth plane curve. Assume that the signed curvature of $\gamma$ at $t_0\in (a,b)$, i.e. $\kappa_*(t_0)$ is nonzero. Then there exists a neighbourhood $U$ of $t_0$ such that for all $\{t_1<t_2<t_3\}\subseteq U$, $\gamma (t_1),\gamma (t_2)$ and $\gamma (t_3)$ does not lie on a straight line.
   $\bf{(}$Let us give a proof of this fact: If not, then we can find a sequence $\{t_{1,n}<t_{2,n}<t_{3,n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that for each $i=1,2,3$, $t_{i,n}\rightarrow t_0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, and $\gamma (t_{1,n}),\gamma (t_{2,n})$ and $\gamma (t_{3,n})$ are colinear, i.e. $\frac{\gamma (t_{2,n})-\gamma (t_{1,n})}{t_{2,n}-t_{1,n}}=\frac{\gamma (t_{3,n})-\gamma (t_{2,n})}{t_{3,n}-t_{2,n}}$, i.e. $\dot{\gamma}(\xi_{1,2,n})=\dot{\gamma}(\eta_{2,3,n})$ for some $\xi_{1,2,n}$ in between $t_{1,n}$ and $t_{2,n}$, and $\eta_{2,3,n}$ in between $t_{2,n}$ and $t_{3,n}$. Now $\ddot{\gamma}(t_0)\neq 0$ and $\gamma$ is smooth, implies $\dot{\gamma}$ is locally injective. But then talking $n\in\mathbb{N}$ large enough, the equality $\dot{\gamma}(\xi_{1,2,n})=\dot{\gamma}(\eta_{2,3,n})$ contradicts that local injectivity.$\bf{)}$

Now I want to prove the following:

**Problem:** There exists an open neighbourhood $U$ of $t_0$ such that the set $\big\{$Radius of circle passing through $\gamma(t_1),\,\gamma(t_2),\,\gamma(t_3)$: $\{t_1<t_2<t_3\}\subseteq U$$\big\}$ is a bounded set.

Note that the signed curvature function $\kappa_*$ for a regular smooth curve $\gamma $ is defined by $\kappa_*=\frac{\ddot{\gamma}\cdot J\dot{\gamma}}{\lVert{\dot{\gamma}}\rVert^3}$, where $J$ is the complex structure on $\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $J(x,y)=(-y,x)$ for $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$.

I got stuck with this problem while studying the notion of Evolute of a smooth regular curve (In particular [Theorem 4.12](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yZwyHtCgtbdjckkXlXcMH9mdAxuBbnY1/view?usp=sharing)) from the book 'Modern Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces with Mathematica' by Abbena, Salamon and Gray. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Not to be rude, but how is this not trivial? You have $\ddot{\gamma}(t_0) \not = 0$, so in a small neighborhood, derivative has to be changing, so can't have three in a line, right?

Comment: Actually I failed to translate the thought into Mathematics. Thanks a lot for your comment. It was trivial indeed. The local injectivity of  $\dot{\gamma}$ ensures it. Could you share your thought for Part 2 of the problem?

Comment: I think it might be annoying to translate into mathematics but I think it should similarly be trivial. it should also follow along the lines of the proof of the first part of the problem. to clarify, I'm not saying it will be easy to do, I'm just saying it is trivial in that it will just follow from $\ddot{\gamma}$ being nonzero

Comment: Following the comment of 'mathworker21', Part 1 of the problem is clear to me now. Hence I am deleting that part.